# Type '() => Bar' is missing the following properties from type 'Bar': x, y

Tags: typescript

First, I apologize for such an elementary question, I have researched this and I am still confused.  The first function compiles fine but the second function below throws this compiler error message: `Type '() => Bar' is missing the following properties from type 'Bar': x, y`.

What is the difference between the two?  Is there anyway to make the second function work?

```js
interface Bar {
  x: Number,
  y: Number
}

class Foo {
  public getBar1(): Bar {
    return { x: 1, y: 2 } as Bar; 
  }

  getBar2: Bar = () => {
    return { x: 1, y: 2 } as Bar
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a complete and total dumb-dumb.  Here is the solution in case you are as big a dummy as me.

```js
interface Bar {
  x: Number,
  y: Number
}

class Foo {
  public getBar1(): Bar {
    return { x: 1, y: 2 } as Bar; 
  }

  getBar2 = (): Bar => {
    return { x: 1, y: 2 } as Bar
  };
}
```